# Pagination problem with ajax page loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have some links on the WordPress archive page that I want to load their content without reloading the page
I was able to do this with the code below, but the problem is that the pagination doesn't load properly!
My theme uses an Ajax pagination that loads the next page by scrolling.
When we are on the main page of the archive and we go to the second page without clicking on the links, and then we click on a link, the Ajax pagination is not loaded on that page! But if we do not go to the second page on the main page of the archive and click on the link, the Ajax pagination will be loaded correctly in that link.
It seems that Ajax pagination is loaded and working only once in every page reload, how can I solve the pagination problem?

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.tag-cattab a').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.tag-cattab a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var tabLink = $(this).attr('href');
            $('.row.posts').empty();
            $.ajax({
                url: tabLink,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(response) {
                    $('.row.posts').html($(response).find('.row.posts').html());
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log('Error: ', error);
                }
            });
        });

        $('.tag-cattab a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
    <div class="tag-cattab">
        <a rel="nofollow" href="https://example.com/blog/tag/photoshop/?cat=1584" class="ntab"><div class="tcattab" >buttontitle1</div></a>
        <a rel="nofollow" href="https://example.com/blog/tag/photoshop/?cat=1588" class="ntab"><div class="tcattab" >buttontitle2</div></a>
    </div>
```

theme archive code:

```
<div class="row posts">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        azin_post_archive_content( get_the_ID(), $col );
    endwhile; ?>
</div>

<div class="col-12 pagination">
    <?php wp_pagination(); ?>
</div>

<?php
//Ajax Load More
if( azin_opt( 'ajax_prod' ) ) {
    ?>
    <div class="col-12 load-more">
        <div class="page-load-status">
            <p class="infinite-scroll-request"><i class="fal fa-spinner-third fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        </div>
        <span id="load-more-button" class="load-more-button btn azin-btn btn-lg"><?php _e( 'Load More Posts', 'azin-file') ?></span>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Also another question, Here we load the content of the links without updating the url and reloading.
And of course the loaded content cannot be cached!
If we update the url, but still do not reload the page, can the page be cached?

I'm beginner, thanks for the help.